# How to fix `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1` error on web3.eth.contract method?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm trying to make a simple function call to a view function that takes a single `uint256` as input, however when I try to pass the variable, next type check gives me this error: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1`.

Here is my code:

```js
const txData = claimContract.methods["viewEvent(uint256)"](eventId)

  const transactionObject = {
    to: claimContract.options.address!,
    data: txData.encodeABI(), 
  };

  const eventData = await web3.eth.call(transactionObject as any);
```

I've console logged the method to ensure it takes an input parameter:

```js
viewEvent: [Function (anonymous)],
  'viewEvent(uint256)': [Function (anonymous)],
  '0x24923f5f': [Function (anonymous)],
```

And also tried the three different web3js syntax from [the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id28):

```js
//const txData = claimContract.methods.viewEvent(eventId);
  //const txData = claimContract.methods["viewEvent(uint256)"](eventId);
  // const txData = claimContract.methods["0x24923f5f"](eventId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an active web3js [GitHub issue](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/6275) about this problem that will hopefully fix this issue in the future.

However, one "*ugly*" [workaround](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/issues/6275#issuecomment-1650199729) to make this work while pleasing next type checks would be to create your data object like this:

```js
const txData = (claimContract.methods.viewEvent as any)(eventId);
```